# NHibernate Criteria Queries - how use in One to One relationship

Tags: nhibernate, entity-relationship, nhibernate-criteria

I  have simple 3 POCO classes:

```
public class User
{
    //PK
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    //ONE to ONE
    public virtual Profil Profil{ get; set; }
    //ONE to MANY
    public virtual IList<PhotoAlbum> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Profil
{
    //PK
    public virtual int ProfilId { get; set; }

    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual int Sex { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoAlbum
{
    //PK
    public virtual int PhotoAlbumId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int NumberOfPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

I created these mapping classes:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            //PK
            Id(p => p.UserId)
               .GeneratedBy.Identity();
            //FK
            References(p => p.Profil)
                .Column("ProfilId")
                .Cascade.All(); 
            //ONE TO MANY
            HasMany(p => p.Albums)
                 .Cascade.All();

            Table("Users");
        }
    }

    public class ProfilMap: ClassMap<Profil>
    {
        public ProfilMap()
        {
            Id(p => p.ProfilId)
                .GeneratedBy.Identity();

            Map(p => p.Age)
                .Not.Nullable();
            Map(p => p.Sex)

            Table("Profiles");
        }
    }

    public class PhotoAlbumMap : ClassMap<PhotoAlbum>
    {
        public PhotoAlbumMap()
        {
            Id(p => p.PhotoAlbumId)
                .GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(p => p.Name)
                .Not.Nullable();
            Map(p => p.NumberOfPhoto)
                .Not.Nullable();
            Table("PhotoAlbums");
        }
    }
```

Then I created simple NHibernate repository class with this method:

```
    public IList<T> GetItemsByCriterions(params ICriterion[] criterions)
    {
        ICriteria criteria = AddCriterions(_session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)),
            criterions);

        IList<T> result = criteria.List<T>();
        return result ?? new List<T>(0);
    }
```

For test I created repository for some entity, for example User:

```
_userRepo = new NHibRepository<User>(NHibeHelper.OpenSession());
```

and I would like have possibility make query in this style:

```
    var users = _userRepo.GetItemsByCriterions(new ICriterion[]
                                                   {
                                                       Restrictions.Gt("Profile.Age",10)
                                                   });
```

this attempt finished with error:

**could not resolve property: Profile of: Repository.User**

User has property Profile type of Profile and this property has properties ProfileId, Age
and sex.

** #1 EDITED:**

@ I tried this:

```
    var users = _userRepo.GetItemsByCriterions(new ICriterion[]
                                                   {
                                                       Restrictions.Where<User>(u=>u.Profil.Sex==0)
                                                   });
```

finished with error:

**could not resolve property: Profil.Sex of: Repository.User**

**#2 EDITED**

I tried use Nathan’s advice:

```
        var result = _userRepo.Session.CreateCriteria<User>()
            .CreateAlias("Profile", "profile", JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("profile.Sex", 0));

        IList<User> users=null;
        if (result != null)
            users = result.List<User>();
```

If I tried convert result to List I again get this error:  **could not resolve property: Profile of: Repository.User**

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example, User has a Profil property not a Profile property.

If it is supposed to be Profil then I would change the `Restrictions.Gt(Profile.Age,10)` to `Restrictions.Gt(Profil.Age,10)` otherwise change the name of the property and mapping to match the query.

Edit:
You are trying to query the User Object.  you need to include the CreateAlias let nhibernate know  that you want to link to a different object.

Try This.

```
var users = session.CreateCriteria<User>() 
  .CreateAlias("Profile", "profile", JoinType.InnerJoin) 
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("profile.Age", 10));
```

Comment: Thank you for advice but when I tried convert users to List<User> I got again same exception : could not resolve property: Profile of: Repository.User

Comment: I have created a bitbucket repository http://bitbucket.org/gonefishern/so_7952683 with very basic test app that shows it working.  if you download the source then you will need to install the packages fluentnhibernate and SqlServerCompact